# When did Ultegra shift from 9 to 10 speed rear cassettes?

Tags: shimano, parts

I'm looking at a used Trek road bike for my daughter. I found an aluminum frame, carbon fork bike with 105 shifters and an Ultegra 9 speed rear derailer. I'm trying to figure out how old the bike is to determine how much I'm willing to pay for it (and how old that carbon front fork is). I own a Cannondale aluminum / carbon road bike with all 105 components and it has a 10 speed read cassette. I purchased tis bike in 2002. So when did Ultegra shift font 9 to 10 speed?

Comment: Four or five years ago, I'd aver.

Comment: I thought derailleurs weren't specific to the number of cogs. If it has 105 shifters, you're probably asking when 105 shifters were 9 speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultegra switched to 10 speed with 6600 model. Judging by Google, Shimano unveiled the groupset in 2004 and it became available [in October 2004](http://forums.roadbikereview.com/general-cycling-discussion/ultegra-10-october-2986.html).

Comment: I believe the 9-speed model was still being sold on new bikes as late as 2008.